# Serilog via Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

I use serilog to log some data and writes it to console and elasticsearch. [ECS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-client.html) supports Geo. Geo can be nested under Client and Host. I use default serilog formatter on official [site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/dotnet/current/serilog-formatter.html). So code example

```cs
EcsTextFormatterConfiguration ecsConfiguration = new()
{
    ...
};
EcsTextFormatter formatter = new(ecsConfiguration);

loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    //Some enrichers
    //....
    .WriteTo.Console(formatter)
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
        new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticUrl))
        {
            CustomFormatter = formatter
        });
```

1. When logs like this `_logger.LogInformation("{geo.name}", "Land of Oz")` then field in kibana is `geo.name` but when using like this  `_logger.LogInformation("{client.geo.name}", "Land of Oz")` then field in kibana is `fields.client.geo.name`. And when uses some custom structured logging construction like '{customLable}' it puts into kibana as 'lables.customLable'. Does it mean that all known nested fields will be put into kibana as `fields.*` and it is ok?
2. Second question is - does exist complete enrichers for Client, **Geo**, **Orchestrator** and other fields presented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-field-reference.html). Or its time to write own enrichers, with complex solution between front and back? :D. Yes I know about [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#available-enricher-packages) and some usefull enrichers from nugetorg like entityframework, but its not enough.